# Unstable text centering in a tableView cell

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I have a strange issue on real devices with centering text in tableView Cell. When running the code on an iPhone 6 (iOS 12.3.1), the code works perfectly well and texts are correctly centered in the cells. But when I run it on an iPhone7 (iOS 12.3.1), the text is justified on the right. When the code is run on Xcode simulator, it works fine.

I am using Xcode 10.2.1 and Xcode does not warn any error.
It seems the problem of text centering depends on the devices (no error at all when running on both real devices).

Below is my code...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Set text label
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 88/255, blue: 205/255, alpha: 1)
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

    // Set font and font size
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size: 17)
}
```

Is there any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: check your constraints

Comment: why are you modifing your cell in willDisplay cell ? you should do it in cellForRow at.

Comment: If you are using constraints then please provide details related to the textLabel's constraints.

Comment: Thanks. Only one constraint: the textLabel is set to 0 on all edges of the cell.

Comment: Make that constraints are not just zero, also check that you have unchecked Constraints to margin when was creating them. They may use SafeArea instead of the superview. Also check constraint of the table view and all possible parents if you have them. Make sure that tableview and cell do not have contentInsets. It will be good to launch visual debugger and make a screenshot to see your views hierarchy

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Will try them. But the thing is that cells are well placed in the VC. No problem here. The issue is that the text itself (inside the text label contained in the cell) do not get centered correctly)

Answer (score 0):

try cellForRowAt indexPath instead of willDisplay cell

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell:tableviewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! tableviewCell
    // Set text label
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 88/255, blue: 205/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

        // Set font and font size
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size: 17)
          return cell
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Indeed... So I gave a try, but the text still remains aligned on the right on iPhone7 whereas it is perfectly well centered on iPhone 6. Strange !

Comment: check your constraints or remove the constraint and use autolayout

Comment: Thanks. For the moment, only one constraint: the textLabel is set to 0 on all edges of the cell.

Comment: Auto layout is on for all screens !